# "kubectl describe ingress ..." could not find the requested resource

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I am trying to execute describe on ingress but does not work. Get command works fine but not describe. Is anything that I am doing wrong? I am running this against AKS.

```
usr@test:/mnt/c/Repos/user/charts/canary$ kubectl get ingress
NAME            HOSTS                              ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
ingress-route   xyz.westus.cloudapp.azure.com                80      6h

usr@test:/mnt/c/Repos/user/charts/canary$ kubectl describe ingress ingress-route
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource
```

Version seems fine:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.3", ..}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.10"...}
```

Comment: this is just a kubernetes cluster, aks doesnt use its own proprietary kubernetes. this should work (and it does work fine for me)

Comment: any clues if you do verbose output for `kubectl describe`?

Comment: You might need to add the namespace where ingress-route resides in.

Comment: Does `kubectl get ingress -o yaml | grep namespace` show anything else than `default` ? As @EdMendez suggested you may need to specify the namespace.

Comment: ref: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/675
This is happening because ingress has been moved to networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 and you are probably using extensions/v1beta1

Answer (score 12):

This could be caused by the incompatibility between the Kubernetes cluster version and the kubectl version.

Run `kubectl version` to print the client and server versions for the current context, example:

```
$ kubectl version

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.1", GitCommit:"d647ddbd755faf07169599a625faf302ffc34458", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-10-02T17:01:15Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13+", GitVersion:"v1.13.10-gke.0", GitCommit:"569511c9540f78a94cc6a41d895c382d0946c11a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-08-21T23:28:44Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.13b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

You might want to upgrade your cluster version or downgrade your kubectl version. See more details in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/675